# SQL query works in phpmyadmin, but PHP fails to send data back to Ionic

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

The following SQL query works if there is more than one student in the class, but not if there is only one. You'll see the use of if/else below.

Now, even if I take out one of the variables (either one), the query doesn't work.

Here is the app on github.pages - https://jamesross06000.github.io/ionic-attendance-app/

login:  nicolesuivant@email.com
password: intervenant

After login, choose agenda and look in the month of September. Highlighted days have lessons listed below, which you click on and a list of students appears, unless the lesson is an 'individuel RDV', where an error is shown in the console log, "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" which I understand to mean no data was passed back to the Ionic ts file.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type");
require_once("connection2.php");
$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);

if (isset($_POST["date"])) {
    $origDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));
    $date = $origDate;
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $id_planning = $_POST['id_planning'];

    $getClasse = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM planning WHERE id_planning = :id_planning");
    $getClasse->execute([':id_planning' => $id_planning]);
    $details = $getClasse->fetchAll();
    $classe = $details[0]['classe'];
    $nom = $details[0]['nom'];
    $lieux = $details[0]['lieux'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `nom` = :nom");
    $stmt->execute([':nom' => $nom]);
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $output = array();
        $output = $stmt->fetchAll();
        var_dump($output);
        $newOutput = array();
        array_push($newOutput, $output, $id_planning, $lieux);
        echo json_encode($newOutput);
    } else {
        $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `classe` = :classe");
        $stmt1->execute([':classe' => $classe]);
        if ($stmt1->rowCount() > 0) {
            $output1 = array();
            $output1 = $stmt1->fetchAll();
            $newOutput1 = array();
            array_push($newOutput1, $output1, $id_planning, $lieux);
            echo json_encode($newOutput1);
        }
    }
}
```

Above is just the relevant PHP file, as it works with a class of several pupils, there's no need to add the ts file just to confuse things further

Comment: What is the purpose of `$stmt->rowCount() > 0`?

Comment: Why do you set `$output1 = array();` to an empty array, just to immediately overwrite it?

Comment: That's how I've learned to do it. If there is nothing returned, no json is echoed. If there is more than 0 results returned, then it continues on and performs the tasks listed below.

Comment: Yes I guess that is not necessary.